# Contact form 7 custom validation

Tags: contact-form-7

I use wppb (https://wppb.me/) for my plugin and I'd like to set a form as invalid.
I would like to invalidate a whole form, not an individual field. This functionality exists in Gravity forms.

I am using this hook:

```
private function define_public_hooks()
{
    $plugin_public = new Unitel_Sim_Registration_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', $plugin_public, 'before_email_send', 10, 2 );
}
```

Though, I'm not sure if wpcf7_before_send_mail is the correct hook for this.

Then:

```
public function before_email_send( $contact_form )
{
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $email = sanitize_email($posted_data['uscr-email']);
    $cvr = sanitize_text_field($posted_data['uscr-cvr']);
    $customer = $this->customer_exists( $email, $cvr ); // checks if email and cvr exist in custom database table, return true or false

    if ( ! $customer )
    {
        // customer does not exist with credentials provided
        // stop form submission and show generic error message, like 'Customer not found'
        // how can I do that?!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `wpcf7_before_send_mail` (which you could do, and use the second parameter passed `$abort`), you could filter the validation for the email field, and simply see if the user exists by email using the wp function `get_user_by( 'email', $email )`

```php
function duck_custom_email_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    if ( in_array( $tag->type, array( 'email', 'email*' ), true ) ) {
        if ( false === get_user_by( 'email', $_POST[ $tag->name ] ) ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, 'Customer not found' );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email', 'duck_custom_email_validation_filter', 20, 2); // Email field.
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'duck_custom_email_validation_filter', 20, 2); // Req. Email field.
```

Based on your follow up question, you need to add a filter for the messages, so you still need the first part, which will invalidate the form, this following function will put your custom message based on the same criteria.

```php
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'filter_response_output', 10, 5 );
function filter_response_output( $output, $class, $content, $contact_form, $status ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['uscr-email'] ) ) { // The name of your email field.
        return $output;
    }
    if ( false === get_user_by( 'email', $_POST['uscr-email'] ) ) { // Again, the name of your email field.
        $atts   = array(
            'class'       => trim( $class ),
            'aria-hidden' => 'true',
        );
        $output = sprintf(
            '<div %1$s>%2$s</div>',
            wpcf7_format_atts( $atts ),
            'customer does not exist with credentials provided' // Your custom message.
        );
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: This invalidates the email field and a 'Customer not found' message would show up on the email field. How can I show the 'Customer not found' message as the main error message? That's the one below the form in red background.

Comment: I've added a second function for that part.